# How much does Captain America eat and poop?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-america

Captain America's metabolism is four times faster than normal humans (Atleast in MCU). He can't get drunk as a result of this.

It got me wondered, how much does Captain America need to eat and poop? His appetite should be higher and he should digest foods faster.

Comment: I'm guessing 4 times as much...

Comment: @Daft Not necessarily. This is a complex thing. There are lots of unknown variables required for calculation. Maybe, canon addresses this.

Comment: Your question is answered in the answer for the above question. I quote "but his altered metabolism might allow his body to transform food more efficiently."